# ReactJS Webpack error type.toUpperCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

So I have my react components bundled into myApp.js using webpack. I have made a global exposed variable called MyApp in my webpack.config.js file that holds all my react components within it - like so:

```
entry: {
// create myApp.js, expose MyApp global object  
// index.js lists all my react components to include in myApp.js
        'myApp.js': 'expose?MyApp!../ReactComponents/index.js'
    },
```

Now in javascript when I use the following  syntax to render my react component I get the error type.toUpperCase is not a function:

```
// MyApp.Employees - MyApp is the global object 
// and Employees is my react component within MyApp global object

    window.onload = function () {
// type is object and not null
// so it is found
alert(MyApp.Employees); 

// react will not render it though
// using this syntax
        React.render(React.createElement(MyApp.Employees, null), document.getElementById('react'));
    }
```

I keep getting the error type.toUpperCase is not a function.

What is the syntax to get react to render MyApp.Employees?

Or what may be causing this error to be raised?

thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you already have `Employees` component created by React, and you're trying to use `createElement` on that component.

Try

```
var Employees = MyApp.Employees;
React.render(<Employees />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately it did not work. The Employees component has not yet been created, it has just been bundled into a .js file by webpack. I am trying to get it out of the webpack using a blobal variable MyApp to then create it. So it is there in my .js file to be created/used, but has not yet been created.

Comment: Here is the start of my Employees component in my webpack .js file...   var Employees = React.createClass({
  displayName: "Employees",
 
  
...
...

Comment: Why do you need expose in the first place?  You can write `module.exports` in React Component module, and then import it where needed, like this: `var Employees = React.createClass(...); module.exports = Employees;` and then `import Employees from ./Components/Employees `, and use it like `React.render(<Employees />,...)`

Comment: Yes, you are correct if you are doing this within the react components using react syntax. But I am using plain javascript to render my react component into the div and am using webpack which bundles the react components into a .js file using its own approach to bundeling the components and how you access them. If you are not bundeling your react components using webpack, and just developing react components and renderrring them, then what I am explaining does not apply to that scenario which may be why my situation seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
String.prototype.toLocaleUpperCase.call('your string');
```

or

```
String.prototype.toUpperCase.call('your string');
```